# Что лучше для связи с бэкэндами: tcp или unix-socket

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, клиент-сервер

Есть проект со следующей структурой:
nginx <-> django <-> postgresql, всё на одной машине.
Сейчас для связи между собой используется tcp.
Имеет ли смысл переделать на unix-socket.
Какие плюсы и минусы есть у каждого из этих решений.
Первое, что приходит на ум - накладные расходы на формирование и "расформирование" tcp-пакетов, в то время как на сокет приходит уже готовый запрос или ответ. Правильно ли я понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае без разницы.

`unixsock` будет чуть дешевле по CPU на большом объёме передаваемых данных. Ну там что-то типа экономии 2-3% CPU usage в softirq на OLTP нагрузке в 40 тысяч запросов в секунду.  Если вы при этом всё ещё сможете уместить приложение и базу на одном хосте.

Поэтому и без разницы в общем случае. Куда важнее работа с самими запросами, настройками ОС и конфигурированием СУБД под свой профиль нагрузки и железо.

---

Впрочем, кроме как `host` адреса подключения так же ничего не меняется для приложения. Проверить необходимо только [`pg_hba`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) правила в конфигурации СУБД. Для подключений через `unixsock` используются правила `local`, для tcp - `host`, `hostssl`, `hostnossl`

Comment: А в случае связки nginx-django выигрыш(?) будет такой же?

Answer (score 0):

Если все на одном машине, то лучше использовать сокету, так как производительность будет выше. 
Переделывать в целом ничего не потребуется, кроме как конфиг gunicorn'a или uwsgi.